# Why does my shader work fine in the Godot editor, but not in runtime?

Tags: glsl, godot, godot-shader-language

I wrote a shader on a CanvasItem in Godot:

```c
shader_type canvas_item;

void fragment() {
    vec2 distortedUV = UV;
    distortedUV.x += sin(distortedUV.y * 5.0 * TIME/100.0 + TIME) * 0.1;
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, distortedUV);
}
```

In the editor it looks like this:

[image: editor shader pic]

However when I run the game, it just slowly moves back and forth with little amplitude and looks like this:

[image: runtime image]

Why is this?
Some more information about my settings:
This is on a TextureRect that is a child of a Control node.
It is a pixel game so setup as such. The window is 360x640 and scaled up to 720x1280 during runtime. Use GPU pixel snap == true. The sprite is a .png imported with the 2D Pixel texture preset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the engine was running for a while, and so it has values of `TIME` bigger than those observed in the game when launching it for testing.

So, in the game, you have a small value of `TIME`, but in the engine you - probably - had a big value of `TIME`.

Now consider the effect of a small value of `TIME` in this expression:

```
distortedUV.y * 5.0 * TIME/100.0 + TIME
```

The value of `TIME/100.0` becomes near zero. So `distortedUV.y * 5.0 * TIME/100.0` becomes near zero, and thus the effect of the vertical coordinate of `distortedUV` becomes negligible.

Answer (score 0):

ok I am answering my own question: this happened because there are two calls to `TIME` in the shader code. This will render consistently between the editor and game. Not sure why the two `TIME` calls makes it this way but that's how it is.

```c
shader_type canvas_item;

void fragment() {
    vec2 distortedUV = UV;
    distortedUV.x += sin(distortedUV.y * 5.0 + TIME) * 0.1;
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, distortedUV);
}
```